# Trying to change label text, when a variable changes automatically without user input

Tags: python, oop, kivy

I am trying to change a label text whenever a variable value changes automatically without any user input.

Using threading I am getting live streaming updates in regards to certain asset parameters. Let's assume Nasdaq.

I don't really understand kivy ObjectProperties but I seem to get the impression that it is possible to change a label text value automatically whenever a variable value changes. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Hope someone can help guide me and with my code.

I know I can change the label text manually by referencing the object id in kivy language then changing the label text. However I want to understand kivy properties better, so I am trying to make the label text change its value whenever a variable value changes automatically through thread streaming without any user interference and inputs.

python code as below:

```
# testing variables
nasdaq_bid_price = ""
nasdaq_ask_price = ""

# this function is called by the thread http response whenever there are auto push updates to any of the values
def on_market_update(item_update):
    global nasdaq_ask_price
    global nasdaq_bid_price

    print(item_update["name"])
    print(item_update["values"]["BID"])
    print(item_update["values"]["OFFER"])
    # output
    '''Nasdaq
    13817.3
    13822.3'''
    if item_update["name"] == "Nasdaq":
        nasdaq_ask_price = item_update["values"]["OFFER"]
        nasdaq_bid_price = item_update["values"]["BID"]

# this is the Class template where it contains some label such as price display, etc and menu buttons. which is shared across multiple screens.
class WindowWithMenuTemplate(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WindowWithMenuTemplate, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        global nasdaq_ask_price
        global nasdaq_bid_price

        nasdaq_ask_display = ObjectProperty(None)
        nasdaq_bid_display = ObjectProperty(None)
        process_available = ObjectProperty(None)
        process_in_automation = ObjectProperty(None)
        process_in_manual = ObjectProperty(None)

        nasdaq_ask_price = StringProperty(None)
        nasdaq_bid_price = StringProperty(None)
```

the structure in my kv contains multiple screens and a screen manager. most of the screens shared a common display of some data fields and a menu button.

thus i have create a WindowWithMenuTemplate Class to house these shared display.

the code below shows the relationship of the root and the WindowWithMenuTemplate Class.

i am trying to change some of the text label value inside of this WindowWithMenuTemplate Class whenever certain values from the thread streaming changes.

kv lang

```
<WindowManager>:
    LoginWindow:
        id: login_window
    HomeWindow:
        id: settings_window
    ExecutionWindow:
        id: execution_window
    OrdersWindow:
        id: orders_window
    AccWindow:
        id: acc_window
    SettingsWindow:
        id: settings_window

<LoginWindow>:
    name: "login_window"

<HomeWindow>:
    name: "home_window"
    WindowWithMenuTemplate:
        id: wwmt

<ExecutionWindow>:
    name: "execution_window"
    WindowWithMenuTemplate:
        id: wwmt

<OrdersWindow>:
    name: "orders_window"
    WindowWithMenuTemplate:
        id: wwmt

<AccWindow>:
    name: "acc_window"
    WindowWithMenuTemplate:
        id: wwmt

<SettingsWindow>:
    name: "settings_window"
    WindowWithMenuTemplate:
        id: wwmt

<WindowWithMenuTemplate>:
    nasdaq_ask_display: nasdaq_ask_display
    nasdaq_bid_display: nasdaq_bid_display

    GridLayout:
        size_hint: 0.9, 0.05
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 0.922}
        cols: 11
        Label:
            # size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
            # pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "top": 0.9}
            text: "Nasdaq"
            font_size: 13

        Label:
            text: "Bid"
            # testing
            text: root.nasdaq_bid_price
            font_size: 13
            id: nasdaq_bid_display

        Label:
            text: "Offer"
            # testing
            text: root.nasdaq_ask_price
            font_size: 13
            id: nasdaq_ask_display
```

I added this line root.nasdaq_ask_price and root.nasdaq_bid_price and receive the error below.

```
 AttributeError: 'WindowWithMenuTemplate' object has no attribute 'nasdaq_ask_price'
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
     value, bound = create_handler(
     raise BuilderException(rule.ctx, rule.line,
```

how should i change it so that the label text value automatically changes whenever a python variable value automatically changes without any user input or interference.

Thank you for the kind help.

Comment: Can you give a more minimal example? It isn't clear what you're doing wrong in this large program

Comment: Hi Inclement, I tried to reduce to a minimal code... hopes it's short enough... basically I want to know if it is possible to change a label text automatically whenever a specific variable changes by itself automatically. without any user input or interference.

Comment: You can use properties to do what you want, but your example is neither minimal nor runnable. I suggest looking at some tutorials like [here](http://inclem.net/2019/12/18/kivy/kivy_tutorial_001_say_hello/) to understand how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I try to reduce the codes.

I am receiving thread http response streaming where it pushes updates whenever the required parameters changes.

for example, I will be receiving live bid and ask prices which keeps on changing.

I want my widget/label text to change when the live bid and ask price change.

I'm not sure if I am mistaken about kivy object properties and string properties. I assume if the string changes, the kivy label text will change accordingly as well?

python code:

```
# this function is called by the thread http response
# whenever there are auto push updates to any of the values
def on_market_update(item_update):
    global nasdaq_ask_price
    global nasdaq_bid_price

    if item_update["name"] == "Nasdaq":
        nasdaq_ask_price = item_update["values"]["OFFER"]
        nasdaq_bid_price = item_update["values"]["BID"]

# this is the Class template where it contains some label
# such as price display, etc and menu buttons. which is shared 
# across multiple screens.
class WindowWithMenuTemplate(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WindowWithMenuTemplate, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        global nasdaq_ask_price
        global nasdaq_bid_price

        nasdaq_ask_display = ObjectProperty(None)
        nasdaq_bid_display = ObjectProperty(None)
        process_available = ObjectProperty(None)
        process_in_automation = ObjectProperty(None)
        process_in_manual = ObjectProperty(None)

        nasdaq_ask_price = StringProperty(None)
        nasdaq_bid_price = StringProperty(None)
```

kv lang

```
<WindowManager>:
    HomeWindow:
        id: settings_window

<HomeWindow>:
    name: "home_window"
    WindowWithMenuTemplate:
        id: wwmt


<WindowWithMenuTemplate>:
    nasdaq_ask_display: nasdaq_ask_display
    nasdaq_bid_display: nasdaq_bid_display

    GridLayout:
        size_hint: 0.9, 0.05
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 0.922}
        cols: 11
        Label:
            # size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
            # pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "top": 0.9}
            text: "Nasdaq"
            font_size: 13

        Label:
            text: "Bid"
            # testing
            text: root.nasdaq_bid_price
            font_size: 13
            id: nasdaq_bid_display

        Label:
            text: "Offer"
            # testing
            text: root.nasdaq_ask_price
            font_size: 13
            id: nasdaq_ask_display
```

Can we change label text whenever a specific variable automatically changes without user input? Am I mistaken about kv properties?

Thank you.